# Simple XML converting Boolean FALSE to SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, simplexml

Can someone explain the following behavior in Simple XML

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( "<score></score>" );
$xml->addChild('test', FALSE);

print_r($xml);
```

Produces

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [test] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)
```

While

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( "<score></score>" );
$xml->addChild('test', TRUE);

print_r($xml);
```

Produces

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [test] => 1
)
```

Why would the `FALSE` value ends up being a `SimpleXMLElement` while `TRUE` isn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$value` argument for [`SimpleXMLElement::addChild`](http://php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) is a string, which can be seen on the documentation page for the method.  After the boolean value is passed to the function, the function changes it to the [string representation of a boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting):

> **Converting to string**
>    A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string).

Comment: `string $name [, string $value [, string $namespace` found in the manual

Comment: Thanks Tim, didn't pay attention to the doc. Should have.